# Function from series summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

There are two variables in time series $Z$ and $S$ depending on $t$. They are formulated as summation of series:

$$\sum_{t=1}^TZ_t=\sum_{t=1}^TS_t-\beta(S_1-S_2-S_{T-1}+S_T)$$

Is there a way to derive a function $f$ to make $Z$t$ = f(S$t$)$, t=1,...,T ?

Reference:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139290/function-from-series-summation

Comment: Do you mean $Z_t=f(S_t)$ for all $t=1,...,T$?

Comment: Write the equation for $T=1$ and $T=1$ and subtract to get $Z_2$, etc. See if you can detect a pattern.

Comment: Yes, Avitus. OP is edited.

Comment: Are you sure $Z_1$ is defined right? As is it reads $Z_1=S_1-\beta(S_1-S_2-S_0+S_1)=S_1-\beta(2S_1-S_2-S_0)$ am I right?  For $Z_2$ I get $S_2+\beta(2S_1-S_0-S_2)$

Comment: Maesumi,you are right. I get the following: $Z_1=S_1 - \beta (2S_1 - S_2 - S_0)$, $Z_2=S_2 + \beta (2S_1 - S_2 - S_0)$, $Z_3=S_3 - \beta (S_1 - 2S_2 + S_3)$, $Z_4=S_4 - \beta (S_2 - 2S_3 + S_4)$......The pattern is $Z_t$ is a linear combination of three neighbor consecutive S. But it does not go further to derive $Z_t = f(S_t)$.